# Hive via ODBC from Java issue: parameters reordered

Tags: java, hive, odbc, prepared-statement, cloudera

I created statement and provided 4 parameters values in proper order. When I executed this - I received wrong result. When I saw into the Job metadata - I saw that conditions were reordered, but parameter values were on the same locations.

Executed statement:

```sql
SELECT l.shipperid
  FROM db.orders l
  JOIN db.customers r ON l.shipperid = r.customerid
  WHERE (l.employeeid > ? AND l.employeeid < ?) OR (r.customerid = ? OR r.customerid = ?)
```

```
statement.setInt(1, 3);
statement.setInt(2, 8);
statement.setInt(3, 1);
statement.setInt(4, 3);
```

From Job Metadata: Hive.query.string:

```sql
SELECT l.shipperid AS c
  FROM db.orders l
  JOIN db.customers r ON (l.shipperid = r.customerid)
  WHERE (((r.customerid = 3) OR (r.customerid = 8)) OR ((l.employeeid > 1) AND (l.employeeid < 3)))
```

If you'll compare these 2 queries you'll see that conditions was reordered, but values - no.

Used latest Cloudera image. Hive 0.12. HiveServer2

Did someone know why it could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you've found a bug in the SQL to HiveQL translation within the driver. I've tested this on the latest Simba Hive release (the Cloudera driver is the same however it is specific to the Cloudera distribution), and it is showing up there as well.

I work for Simba, and have let our engineers know about this and they're going to look into it. If you are a Cloudera customer you can contact them and they'll then work with you and us to resolve the issue. If you are not, or you use the Apache version, you can contact us directly for a fix.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Due to limited time I implemented workaround with generating entire query without using parameter. Hopfully it will be resolved and helps someone else.